# How do I find the 2 most frequent letters in a string and return a new string with them with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I'm working on a problem that ask to take a string `string` and return a new string with the 2 most frequent letters in the `string` in alternating order.

my code:

```
var word = "pponoomababaaa";
var len = word.length;

function twoLetters (word){
var arr = []
word = word.split("")
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    if ((arr[word[i]])) arr[word[i]] += 1
    else arr[word[i]] = 1
  }
return arr  // [ p: 2, o: 3, n: 1, m: 1, a: 5, b: 2 ]
}
twoLetters(word)
```

This returned `arr` has a length of 0, which I don't understand, so I can't really do anything with it.  I have tried putting it into an object but it still has the same issue.  How do get `arr` to equal a key:value pair and then find the 2 highest `values` and them add the `keys` to a string in alternating order.  Am I going in the right direction with the code I have?

Comment: Use `{}`, not `[]`.

Comment: Your `arr` is not empty. After setting the keys in your `arr`, it was turned into an object.

Comment: Please let us know what worked for you and consider accepting answer it helps other to understand what is the right solution when something like this comes up

Answer (score 2):

It works if you change your array to an object:

```
var word = "pponoomababaaa";
var len = word.length;

function twoLetters (word){
  var arr = {}
  word = word.split("")
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    if ((arr[word[i]])) arr[word[i]] += 1
    else arr[word[i]] = 1
  }
  return arr  // { p: 2, o: 3, n: 1, m: 1, a: 5, b: 2 }
}

twoLetters(word)
```

In JavaScript, arrays (`[]`) don't contain key-value pairs (well, sort of: the indexes are keys so-to-speak). The data structure you're looking for is a plain object (`{}`), which can hold key-value pairs.

**Edit**

Just to add a bit of clarification, you can add members onto an array (`[]`), but your array length will be 0. Here's the output from my browser console in Chrome, where you can see that you can add members onto the array itself. However this approach isn't recommended.

[image]

Comment: The `{}` or `[]` makes no difference.

Comment: @Omeed2, are you sure about it?

Comment: Yes, go ahead and try and you'll get the same result. It's creating a key:value object, not an array. You can access arr.p but not arr[0]

Comment: @Omeed2 you're right, but it's probably not appropriate for the OP's case.

Comment: Well I think it does. He would need to `push` into `arr` to make it an array, otherwise it's just an object.

Comment: @Omeed2, no, a plain object `{}` is the appropriate data structure for the OP's use case.

Comment: Yes, except he's asking about an array and thinks he's making an array. And judging by the variable name `arr` I'm guessing he wants an array. I don't really care to tell him that he should be using a object, that's not what he asked.

Comment: Object or array, how do I loop through those keys though?  I know that arr.a = 5  arr.b = 2; but how do I compare all of them and return the 2 highest

Comment: This is still just what I got @JoshBeam

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for this

```js
var myMap = new Map();
var word = "pponoomababaaa";
var chars = word.split("");

chars.forEach(function(char) {
  if (!myMap.get(char)) {
    myMap.set(char, 1);
  } else {
    var count=myMap.get(char);
    count+=1;
    myMap.set(char,count);
  }
});

for (var [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
//if to copy to new array
var newarr=Array.from(myMap);
console.log(newarr);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var word = "pponoomababaaa";
var len = word.length;

function twoLetters (word){
var arr = []
word = word.split("")
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    if ((arr[word[i]])) arr[word[i]] += 1
    else arr[word[i]] = 1
  }
console.log(arr.p)
return arr  // [ p: 2, o: 3, n: 1, m: 1, a: 5, b: 2 ]

}
twoLetters(word)
```

You're not creating an array, you're creating an object. It does have a key:value pair, as you'll see in the `console.log(arr.p)` For it to be an array, you would need to `push` into arr.

Comment: When I created an object or an array I got the same thing.  How do I set an element for each key:value? How do I loop through those keys? I know that arr.a = 5 arr.b = 2; but how do I compare all of them and return the 2 highest?

Comment: `console.log($.each(arr, function(key, value) { console.log(value); }));`

Comment: Did that help? I can see it working in console, upvote and check if it helped you out :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is your updated code with `arr` as an object(`{}`) not an array(`[]`)

```js
var word = "pponoomababaaa";
var len = word.length;

function twoLetters (word){
var arr = {};
word = word.split("")
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    if ((arr[word[i]])) arr[word[i]] += 1
    else arr[word[i]] = 1
  }
return arr;  // [ p: 2, o: 3, n: 1, m: 1, a: 5, b: 2 ]
}
console.log(twoLetters(word))
```

Setting keys in array would turn it into an object. Your `arr = []` was working fine in jsbin(http://jsbin.com/povimehiyu/)(check the console). But not here in code snippet, hence modified `arr = {}`

- Adding key-value in object won't create/update the `length` property.
- In your code  above, adding key in `arr` changed it into an object, and `length` property was not updated whenever who were setting a key-value in your `arr`

Comment: Would have been nice if you explained what you did.